# Concatenating C strings in linear time with crt

Tags: c, string, crt, concatenation, strcat

Say we want to concatenate const char *s[0], s[1], ... s[n-1] into one long char out[] in C.

Formally (ignoring buffer overruns, for simplicity):

```
void concatManyStrings(char out[], const char *s[], size_t n);
```

It is a trivial task, of course: start with a pointer to out and advance it for every char,
while looping through the input strings.

Another approach (which is still linear-time) would be to keep a pointer to the end,
and with each s[i] do:

```
{ strcpy(endp, s[i]); endp += strlen(s[i]); }
```

But, the code would be cleaner if there was a standard CRT function that knows how to `strcpy()`,
and return the number of copied chars (or equivalently, a pointer to the next char after the copied).

The only CRT function I can think of that does that is `sprintf()`, but it is obviously not nearly
as efficient as a simple `strcpy()` that returns count.

Is there such a function that I'm missing?

Comment: The time will be linear in the size of the strings in your `s` unless you do something weird like using `strcat()` without adjusting the start point at which concatenation occurs.

Comment: "crt"?  Cathode ray tube?  I presume you meant "C runtime", but "standard library" would probably have been clearer.

Comment: @Keith: CRT is a common initialism for the C runtime (though it's more popular with Microsoft than in other circles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlcpy()` and `strlcat()` are non-standard, unfortunately, but if you happen to have them, you can use them for this.  They both return results that let you determine the *end* of the copied string, unlike `strcpy()` and `strcat()` which (somewhat uselessly) return a pointer to the start of the destination.

Answer (score 1):

You can't afford to ignore buffer overruns; that's one of the main ways the web world crashes.

Given the data structure shown, there is a limit to what you can do.  If the data structure included the lengths of each of the strings in the data passed to the function, there'd be more you can do.  However, until then, you have to determine the length of each string (and supply the length of the output buffer), and then arrange to safely copy the strings.  Since by the time you are copying you will know the length of the string, you can use `memmove()` or `memcpy()` to move the data, and you know the length so you can adjust the pointer:

```
int concatManyStrings(char *buffer, size_t buflen, const char **data, size_t nitems)
{
    assert(buflen > 0);
    char *dst = buffer;
    char *end = buffer + buflen - 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nitems; i++)
    {
         size_t len = strlen(data[i]);
         if (dst + len >= end)
             return -1;
         memmove(dst, data[i], len);
         dst += len;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```

This scans each string twice - once for the length and once for copying.  However, you can't afford to use `strncpy()` because of its null-padding behaviour (diabolical in this context); the fact that it doesn't guarantee null termination would not be a problem.  You can't use `strcpy()` until you know that the length is safe, which requires the `strlen()`.  If the data was not a simple array of pointers to strings but an array of a structure that included the length of the string as well as the pointer, then the `strlen()` could be avoided.  With caution, it might be feasible to use `strcat()` or `strncat()`; the primary caution would be to avoid quadratic behaviour (Schlemiel's Algorithm), which can be done by ensuring you determine the end of each added string.  In the case of `strncat()`, be very careful with the size parameter; it is different from what `strncpy()` gets as a size.  And you are still likely to need to use `strlen()` as the standard functions do not report the end of string where they placed the last character - which would be vastly more helpful than returning a pointer to the first character of the target string.

There isn't a standard function to do this that I know of.

Comment: Of course I can afford to ignore buffer overruns: this is just a narrow question regarding a missing crt function, and has nothing to do with crashing the web nor the world...

Comment: GNU has the [`stpcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stpcpy) function, which returns a pointer to the *end* of the string, but it's very non-standard.

Comment: You **cannot** afford to ignore buffer overruns.  Period.  Even if your application will never go anywhere near the web, you have to be sure you will not overrun your buffer if your program is not to crash.  Even if you do it by (over-)allocating space for the target string, you have to worry about it.  If you don't, you programs will crash and burn.

Comment: Oy, Jonathan, Jonathan. Not all programmers are equally anal. Some of us program for 30 years, enjoy an occasional buffer overrun, and have never ever seen a program burn.

Answer (score 0):

Use `snprintf`, which is basically always the right answer to any question about assembling strings:

```
snprintf(buf, buflen, "%s%s%s", str1, str2, str3);
```

Unfortunately this does not work for "arbitrary `n`" as the input string count; for that just write your own for loop...

Comment: ... which is basically always the right answer if you don't care about performance (in which case, python would provide more elegant solutions) ;-)

Comment: You can still use `snprintf` in a loop for arbitrarily many strings, you just need to either use the return value or the `%n` modifier to get the number of characters written.  Of course, even then, I bet it'd be slower than doing a `strcpy` and extra `strlen` call, since those functions use heavily-optimized assembly which `snprintf` can't take advantage of.

Comment: If you're going to use the ugly loop and multiple "concatenation" steps you might as well use `strlen` and `memcpy` yourself. No point in using `snprintf`. The **only** point in using `snprintf` is not to perform pointer arithmetic and buffer-length arithmetic **at all** so that there's no possibility of getting it wrong.